# Magento 2 filter with custom customer attribute in create order select customer grid

Tags: magento2

I am working on Magento 2. In admin -> Sales -> Order create order it is displaying all customer list. I want to filter that list with custom customer attribute. I already created attribute.

**Example :**

Customer Attribute : Allow to create order -> Yes / No

In create order customer list only those customer should display which attribute value is "Yes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a while but I got it, hopefully you can get it working too:

Make a module with a registration.php, etc/module.xml and the usual stuff composer.json. Use a extension generator or something online maybe..

Then make a etc/di.xml file in your module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer\Collection" type="Eighties\CustAttr2\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer\Collection" />     
</config>
```

Then make Setup/InstallData.php in your module:

```
<?php

namespace Eighties\CustAttr2\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, Config $eavConfig)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig       = $eavConfig;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'allow_customer_order_create',
            [

                'label'                 => 'Allow customer creating orders',
                'input'                 => 'boolean',
                'required'              => false,
                'sort_order'            => 900,
                'visible'               => true,
                'system'                => false,
                'is_used_in_grid'       => false,
                'is_visible_in_grid'    => false,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
                'default'               => 0
            ]
        );
        $sampleAttribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'allow_customer_order_create');

        // more used_in_forms ['adminhtml_checkout','adminhtml_customer','adminhtml_customer_address','customer_account_edit','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address']
        $sampleAttribute->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            ['adminhtml_customer']

        );
        $sampleAttribute->save();
    }
}
```

Then make Model/ResourceModel/Order/Customer/Collection.php in the module

```
<?php
/**
 * Customer Grid Collection
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Eighties\CustAttr2\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer;

class Collection extends \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection
{
    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();
        $this->addNameToSelect()->addAttributeToSelect(
            'email'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'created_at'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'allow_create_order'
        )->joinAttribute(
            'billing_postcode',
            'customer_address/postcode',
            'default_billing',
            null,
            'left'
        )->joinAttribute(
            'billing_city',
            'customer_address/city',
            'default_billing',
            null,
            'left'
        )->joinAttribute(
            'billing_telephone',
            'customer_address/telephone',
            'default_billing',
            null,
            'left'
        )->joinAttribute(
            'billing_regione',
            'customer_address/region',
            'default_billing',
            null,
            'left'
        )->joinAttribute(
            'billing_country_id',
            'customer_address/country_id',
            'default_billing',
            null,
            'left'
        )->joinField(
            'store_name',
            'store',
            'name',
            'store_id=store_id',
            null,
            'left'
        )->joinField(
            'website_name',
            'store_website',
            'name',
            'website_id=website_id',
            null,
            'left'
        );
        return $this->addAttributeToFilter('allow_customer_order_create', array('eq' => 1));
    }
}
```

'allow_customer_order_create' is the attribute name.

Then run setup:upgrade and all the command to get the site back up (static-content etc) , and clear caches.

n.b. In case your attribute generates the first time and the no more... delete the module entry from the 'setup_module' table in your database.

In case you don't need to make the attribute anymore just leave the InstallData.php out.. And change the attribute name to your attribute name.

Hope you get it working!